# Create Trigger for assigning value for null

Tags: sql, t-sql, triggers, ssms

I'm trying to create a trigger in SSMS where if Email is null for a new inserted row then add email using FirstName + LastName + '@gmail.com'

Here's what I have so far but it definitely doesn't look correct:

```
Drop Trigger if exists trg_assignEmail
Go
Create Trigger 
    trg_assignEmail 
On StudentInformation
For Insert 
As
Begin
    Insert Into StudentInformation
    Set Email = Null
    Select rtrim(FirstName + LastName) + '@gmail.com'
    From StudentInformation
Where Email is Null
```

Schema:

```
Create Table StudentInformation (
    StudentID int not null identity (100,1),
    Title nchar(50) null, 
    FirstName nchar (50) null,
    LastName nchar (50) null,
    Address1 nchar (50) null,
    Address2 nchar (50) null,
    City nchar (50) null, 
    County nchar (50) null,
    Zip nchar (10) null, 
    Country nchar (50) null,
    Telephone nchar (50) null,
    Email nchar (50) null, 
    Enrolled nchar (50) null,
    AltTelephone nchar(50) null
    Constraint PK_StudentID Primary Key (StudentID)
);
```

Comment: You are creating a table everytime you are inserting in the table, is it normal ? Don't forget to write END at the end of your trigger declaration.

Comment: Why take the time to write a question but actually test it?

Answer (score 0):

You trigger code raises various errors : to start with, `INSERT ... SET ... FROM ...` is not valid SQL syntax.

I think that a relevant approach for your use case would be to create an `AFTER INSERT` trigger, that will inspect the values that were just inserted (using pseudo-table `inserted`), and update the `Email` if needed.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_assignEmail ON StudentInformation
AFTER INSERT
As
BEGIN
    UPDATE s
    SET s.Email = TRIM(i.FirstName) + TRIM(i.LastName) + '@gmail.com'
    FROM StudentInformation s
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.StudentID = s.StudentID AND i.email IS NULL
END
```

The `INNER JOIN` on `inserted` is used to select the record that was just inserted, *if* no `Email` was given.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1da709c986753401ad2a89bc444c516b)**:

```
insert into StudentInformation(Title, FirstName, LastName) values('Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz');
select Title, FirstName, LastName, Email from StudentInformation;
```

```
Title | FirstName | LastName | Email                                             
:-----| :---------| :--------| :----------------
Foo   | Bar       | Baz      | BarBaz@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

for pre-2017, try. not that [trim()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) couldn't be replaced with rtrim() or ltrim() and also handles empty string (common with applications when using a form to save)

```
Create Trigger 
    trg_assignEmail 
On StudentInformation
For Insert 
As
Begin
    declare @email as nchar(50)
        ,@id int
    select @email = Email, @id = StudentID from inserted
    if nullif(@email,'') is null 
        begin
            update StudentInformation
            set Email = rtrim(FirstName + LastName) + '@gmail.com'
            where StudentID = @id
        end
end
```